# Create PDF with JavaScript and upload automatically?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, html2canvas, jspdf

I'm using JSPDF with html2canvas to create reports from web pages that are exported to PDF. I also have `contentEditable` equal to true so the user can customize the reports before the PDF is generated. I would like to add the ability to email the PDF. Is there a way to upload the PDF I generated automatically to my server so I can email it out? We don't have to support older browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like JSPDF has an `output()` method that will give a Base64 encoded string of the PDF which can be uploaded via a normal AJAX call!